# Driver info: driver.version: unknown at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select.<init>(Select.java:46) at com.myfirst.Main5.main(Main5.java:24)

Tags: java, selenium

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/SignUpcontinue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2FManageAccount");
Select drpGender = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("Gender")));
drpGender.selectByVisibleText("MALE");
```

I am trying to select option on drop down box but m getting an error.For error plz refer Title/Subject

Thanks,
Arihant

Answer (score 0):

The element with id Gender is under a **div tag**. There is no **select** tag present. `Select` class is applicable only to elements with tagname - **select**.
In order to perform your task, you can do:

```
d.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Gender']/div[1]/div[2]")).click();
d.findElement(
    By.xpath("//div[@class='goog-menuitem-content'][.='Male']"))
        .click();
```