# Selenium - How do I get the the list of options of a drop down list using java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the following code:

```
<span class="dropDown">Choose</span>
<div class="dropdownQuestions active" style="display: block; max-height: 310px;">
<span data-index="0" data-value="1" onclick="gt.setQuestion(this, true);">Warrior</span>
<span data-index="1" data-value="2" onclick="gt.setQuestion(this, true);">Mage</span>
<span data-index="2" data-value="3" onclick="gt.setQuestion(this, true);">Sorcerer</span>
```

And what I want, if possible, is a list of the the drop down list so after I can use one of them to click, I have searched a lot and could not find any answer that would help me.

Other option would be to click using the data-index, or data-value String.
the last option I would want is clicking by the String "Warrior", "Mage" or "Sorcerer", but if there is no other way, Ill be glad with that.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After clicking on the dropdown, you can get all the dropdown options in a list and later use them as you want(looping and selecting the desired option with specific condition or getting option by index).

```
  List<WebElement> options= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='dropDown']/div/span"));
  options.get(1).click(); // here 1 is the index value of the option to select or you can use loop if looking for some specific condition
```

For the image link you shared in the comment, try the following cssSelector:

```
List<WebElement> option= driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.questionDropdownOptions.activeSelectMenu span"));
                option.get(1).click();
    }
```

Note: Please import below packages in your code:

```
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but im getting "InvalidSelectorException"
The dropDown appears when I click, the div class is the one that has the chooses inside(spans). I just started using selenium so not sure...
I inspected the code and copied the xpath and added it to your code example...

I have this image as example: https://ibb.co/1XrdRRf

Thats what I want, the list of coiches inside that div, for me to use them as I please later.
As I said I tried do copy the xpath/full xpath from that div to your example. but no luck

Thanks for your time!

Comment: @TiagoMachado InvalidSelectorException occurs when there is syntax error in code. Because I was not on my pc I replied via phone. I will check and get back to you in a while.

Comment: @TiagoMachado , I have updated my answer based on your comment. Please check if it solves your problem.

Comment: wow! I dont know how to thank you! working perfectly now!!!!!
THANK YOU! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

I think that all what are you looking for has already been answered here:

-> [How to select a dropdown value in Selenium WebDriver using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138761/how-to-select-a-dropdown-value-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

and if you want to iterate through it, this might be helpful

-> [How to count the number of options in a select drop down box in Selenium WebDriver using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20210853/how-to-count-the-number-of-options-in-a-select-drop-down-box-in-selenium-webdriv)

To be more specific, in a first link, you can see that you can click on the dropdown option using String parameter and also you can use an index.

I know you were probably looking for a specific code, but sadly, I am not on a computer, but I am pretty sure that this answer's your question.

Good luck with your code :)

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, but saddly, Select only works with a select tag present, as answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28322816/driver-info-driver-version-unknown-at-org-openqa-selenium-support-ui-select-i